# spread spectrum communication in airport

Tags: digital-communications

Does anyone know , how the spread spectrum sequences are used in airports. I've attended a presentation this morning regarding spread spectrum in my college, the author mentioned that the sequences are helpful in landing of the aircraft, and also to mitigate interference between air crafts. How is that possible? Is it like assigning a unique code to every aircraft?

Thanks in advance,
phani tej

Comment: This is too broad a question for anyone to expect an answer to be written out in any detail. Please ask a more narrowly-focussed question.

Comment: Ok let me put that ,this way. other than CDMA/GPS, what are the other civilian applications where spread spectrum is used, but we are not aware of that. The deployment/application can be very minor also..